# Adding GeoPackages from geoserver-rest

Tags: python, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have a bunch of GeoPackages that I want to load into datastore then publish in GeoServer.
Previously I have been just manually adding the datastores which I now want to try to automate some of the steps.

I have GeoServer 2.24.2 installed, as well as geoserver-rest.
Reading up the documentation and just following along the basic steps for testing, I can't seem to get the datastore for the GeoPackage to load. In the stores section I get ! for Data Type, and I am unable to expand on the store name to see the properties. When I manually add a new data store for the same geopackage it works. I also tried to copy the file path of the 'working' store in the py to see if it was a path issue but it is the same.

What could be the issue?

```
from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver
geo = Geoserver('http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver', username='admin', password='geoserver')

geo.create_workspace(workspace='demo')
geo.create_datastore(name="test", path=r'C:\test.gpkg', workspace='demo')
geo.create_datastore(name="test1", path=r'file://C:\test.gpkg', workspace='demo')
```

[image: note the ! Data Type and ? Type]

Comment: Load one via the gui and do a get request to see what to send in your post/put